# Android List View and images

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I have a listview that displays player names from a datastore class and i would like it to also display an images of the player. how can i change my listview to display images aswell?

This is my code to populate the listview:

```
    player_List = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listplayer); 

    player_List.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Player>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataStore.getPlayers()));
```

any help will greatly be appreciated!

By the way i tried a simple array adapter but that only seems to like string objects! and i want to put a player object!

Thanks

Comment: use search "android listview custom adapter"

Comment: create a custom adapter.

Comment: You need to create custom listView for this. Search on google. You will get so many examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check below link

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/